# Why does my window not display the image I drew in my JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, jpanel

I'm trying to make a slideshow program using java swing, essentially images are added and then 2 buttons allow you to go forward and back.

```
package javaSwingLearning;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ScreenShow2 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    private ImagePanel imagePanel = new ImagePanel();
    private JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    private JButton previousButton = new JButton();
    private JButton nextButton = new JButton();
    private JButton exitButton = new JButton();
    private ArrayList<BufferedImage> images = new ArrayList<>();
    private int position = -1;
    public ScreenShow2() {
        this.add(mainPanel);
        mainPanel.add(buttonPanel);
        mainPanel.add(imagePanel);
        buttonPanel.add(nextButton);
        buttonPanel.add(previousButton);
        buttonPanel.add(exitButton);
        nextButton.setText("Next");
        nextButton.addActionListener(this);
        previousButton.setText("Back");
        previousButton.addActionListener(this);
        exitButton.setText("Close");
        exitButton.addActionListener(this);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
    private BufferedImage loadImages(String imgPath) {
        try {
            return ImageIO.read(new File(imgPath));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("image does not exist");
        
        }
        return null;

    }
    
    public void addImage(String imagePath) {
        BufferedImage tempImage = loadImages(imagePath);
        if (tempImage != null){
            images.add(tempImage);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ScreenShow2 thing = new ScreenShow2();
        thing.addImage("src/javaSwingLearning/hornet.png");
        
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (e.getSource().equals(exitButton)) {
            System.out.println("button works");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        if (e.getSource().equals(nextButton)) {
            System.out.println("nextButton works");
            if (images.size() != 0) {
                System.out.println("made it past size gate");
                position++;
                imagePanel.setImage(images.get(position));
            }
        }
package javaSwingLearning;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {
    private BufferedImage image;
    
    @Override
      protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 810, 1440, null);
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }
    public void setImage(BufferedImage image) {
        System.out.println("into setImage");
        paintComponent(this.getGraphics());
        this.image = image;
        
    }
```

sorry if this is too much code for what was needed, I just felt I should cover all my bases
Essentially the code passes all the right information to the imagePanel I made but it won't actually display it in the window. Is this a simple fix or a fundamental problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 810, 1440, null);
    super.paintComponent(g);
```

Your code is drawing an image and then invoking `super.paintComonent()` which paints the background of the panel over top of the image.

The proper order should be:

```
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage (image, 0, 0, 810, 1440, null);
```

Why are you hardcoding 810, 1440? My screen resolution is 1024 x 768?

If you are trying to fill the entire area of the panel then you should be using the `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` methods.

```
paintComponent(this.getGraphics());
this.image = image;
```

Never invoke the paintComponent(...) method directly. Swing will invoke that method when the components needs to be repainted.

Instead you just invoke the `repaint()` method.

How do you expect to paint the new image if you don't change the image variable until AFTER you try to paint the component?

Comment: I'm hard coding a size, to see if it'll perfectly fit the image I'm using to test with, once I get that, all images will be resized to fit the panel. Also thanks for the help, I'll try it with repaint() now, and get back to you!

Comment: I have ran into some issues
first of all I dont know where to call repaint(), also I don't know where my Jpanel is supposed to be, can I give it specific coordinates to be at?

Comment: *dont know where to call repaint(),* - I already answered that.